# Why Apache Cassandra not starting up on windows XP?

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, nosql

I am trying to run Cassandra from Windows XP machine.My JDK version is 1.7 and Cassandra version is 2.0.8.
Here is my configuration in cassandra yaml file.

```
commitlog_directory:<CommitLogDirectory>C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/storage/commitlog</CommitLogDirectory>

data_file_directories:
    - <DataFileDirectory>C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/storage/data</DataFileDirectory>

saved_caches_directory: <SavedCachesDirectory>C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/storage/savedcaches</SavedCachesDirectory>
```

But the following exception is thrown:

```
ERROR 18:26:34,375 Fatal configuration error
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Invalid yaml
Caused by: while scanning a simple key
 in 'reader', line 100, column 1:
    commitlog_directory:<CommitLogDi ...
    ^
could not found expected ':'
 in 'reader', line 102, column 1:
    # policy for data disk failures:
```

Please tell me any solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Your yaml file is invalid. You should remove the `<>,</>` tags.

Comment: what do you mean by 'remove <>,</> tags'?

Comment: It should be 'commitlog_directory: C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/storage/commitlog' rather than 'commitlog_directory:<CommitLogDirectory>C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/storage/commitlog</CommitLogDirectory>'. kkmishra is also right, you need a space after the colon too.

Comment: I tried your way.But following thing is happening:ERROR 21:14:55,407 Directory <DataFileDirectory>C:/Documents and Settings/Admini
strator/Desktop/GOD MODE/storage/data</DataFileDirectory> doesn't exist
ERROR 21:14:55,423 Has no permission to create <DataFileDirectory>C:/Documents a
nd Settings/Administrator/Desktop/storage/data</DataFileDirectory> dire
ctory

Comment: You need to remove the <DataFileDirectory> and </DataFileDirectory> tags too. There are no such tags in yaml.

Comment: what about <SavedCachesDirectory> tag?

Comment: Yes, that too. There are no tags in yaml, I don't know where they came from in your yaml file.

Comment: Something is happening.I am describing the thing as a answer in next para

Answer (score 0):

Provide a space after commitlog_directory property i.e.

```
commitlog_directory: <CommitLogDirectory>
```